# how to show the selected html multiple colors and pushing into an array and to display it? color is displaying multiple times when its appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

> javascript

```
function fetchc(){
pclr=document.getElementById("product_color").value;
clr.push(pclr);
var n=clr.length;
$("#colors").show();
 for (var i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
$("#colors").append('<input type="color" value="'+clr[i]+'" disabled>')
 }
 console.log(clr);
}
```

> html

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">
    <label for="product_color"> Select product Color</label>&emsp;
    <input type="color" class="form-control" id="product_color"placeholder="Product color" style="width: 100px;" onchange="fetchc();">
    <div id="colors" style="display: none;"></div>
  </div>
```

**im getting the correct output but with respect to array length its getting appended multiple times... i just want it to show single time**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an `html` content and replace with exist `colors` html

```js
var clr = []
function fetchc(){
pclr=document.getElementById("product_color").value;
clr.push(pclr);
var n=clr.length;
$("#colors").show();
var html = "";
 for (var i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
html += '<input type="color" value="'+clr[i]+'" disabled>';
 }

 $("#colors").html(html);
/*  OR don't use for loop just append */
/* $("#colors").append('<input type="color" value="'+pclr+'" disabled>')*/
 
 console.log(clr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group form-inline">
    <label for="product_color"> Select product Color</label>&emsp;
    <input type="color" class="form-control" id="product_color"placeholder="Product color" style="width: 100px;" onchange="fetchc();">
    <div id="colors" style="display: none;"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you invoke `fetchc()` you iterate over your `clr` array, so you add your previous selections all over again.

Assuming you declared `clr` outside this function, you can see this example:

```
const addedColors = [];
function fetchc(){
  const selectedColor = document.getElementById("product_color").value;
  console.log(`selectedColor is ${selectedColor}`);
  addedColors.push(selectedColor);
  addedColors.map((color) => {
    console.log(`adding color ${color}`)
  })
```

In this case the output will be

> selectedColor is #004080
>   adding color #004080
>   selectedColor is #400040
>   adding color #004080
>   adding color #400040
>   selectedColor is #400080
>   adding color #004080
>   adding color #400040
>   adding color #400080

And as you can see you just added the first color (004080) 3 times.

So instead, just add the new color (also you don't need jQuery for this):

```
function fetchc(){
  const selectedColor = document.getElementById("product_color").value;
  console.log(`selectedColor is ${selectedColor}`);
  const newInput = document.createElement("input");
  newInput.type = 'color';
  newInput.value = selectedColor;
  document.getElementById("colors").appendChild(newInput);
  addedColors.push(selectedColor);
}
```